# python - read header from raw image file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this raw image file https://ufile.io/5b0191 . The format of the image is 12-bit unpacked. 
My question is: Can I read header from this file especially key header word TIMESTAMP? In this case timestamp is not time but number of ticks of internal generator of the camera.
How I can read TIMESTAMP?
Thanks Tom

Comment: What makes you think that there _is_ any header info in that file? Perhaps it's literally a raw file, i.e., just the pixel data with no other data. What's the pixel size of the image?

Comment: Perhaps the timestamp info is encoded in the file name.

Answer (score 0):

[PIL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PIL) would be my best bet. It has an exif reader. And I *guess* that the TIMESTAMP is in there. 
Don't have time to try it out myself at the moment, but I hope it helps at least a little bit.

For Python 3.x that would be Pillow, as @Peter Wood mentioned.

Comment: thanks for answer...but it seen that somthing is wrong with file. In GIMP I dont open it but in Gwenview it is OK...